# TimeZoneInfo bug in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I have recently updated my os with .net 4.5 framework and compiled all my applications using it. 
unfortunately some of the automatic tests i wrote now fails on the Assert constructions concerning DateTime types.

After a deep analysis i turned out this:

in .net 4.0

```
DateTime dateUsing40 = new DateTime(2011, 4, 7); // ticks 634377312000000000    
dateUsing40.ToUniversalTime(); //ticks **634377240000000000

bool isDaylightST = dateUsing40.IsDaylightSavingTime(); // returns **true
```

in .net 4.5

```
DateTime dateUsing45 = new DateTime(2011, 4, 7); // ticks 634377312000000000
dateUsing45.ToUniversalTime(); //ticks  **634377276000000000    
bool isDaylightST = dateUsing45.IsDaylightSavingTime(); // returns **false
```

the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is in both cases {it-IT}

Actually the date i used is in the range of the (italian but also for all countries that use WET) daylight time so it looks like there is a (huge) bug in the framework. however i didn't find anything useful about.

I verified in both machines:

- regional settings are still set in Italian.
- "Automatically adjust clock for daylight saving changes" is checked.
- opening Regional and settings-> on tab Location -> current location is still Italy.
- os Windows 7 x64

SOLVED:

the framework update changed the DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled's value to 1. To solve this issue it's necessary to turn it to 0 and rebooting. Another way to do it is using the clock UI form.

Comment: Use [`NodaTime`](http://nodatime.org/). .NET `DateTime` class have some troubles.

Comment: Does not reproduce here. Are you sure about the `CurrentCulture`. Has the regional settings of Windows been changed on the .NET 4.5 machine?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either. Both using my own culture (nl-BE) and it-IT.

Comment: When you run the test, were the timezone and "Automatically adjust clock for daylight saving changes" settings the same?

Comment: Setting the `CurrentCulture` does not seem to be enough. Tested that. There are some OS settings "not Italian" on your 4.5 machine. Open "Region and Language" in Windows, go to tab "Location". What does it say?

Comment: I tend to be veeery careful before assuming bugs in the framework. While there are some, mostly problems arise from other sources.

Comment: i'm veryfying the os settings but immediately i can say that i made the tests run before the framework update and they all worked. I didn't change any settings(at least explicitly), update the framework and then i got this problem.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen please note the question updates

Comment: @JensenSomers please note the question updates

Comment: Try the new hints I just added to my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of `var tziLocal = TimeZoneInfo.Local;` (cf. Shaun's answer), and its `Id` property.

Equivalently (I think), go to PowerShell and write:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation -Name TimeZoneKeyName
```

and check the value of `TimeZoneKeyName` winreg "property". `Get-ItemProperty` can be shortened to just `gp`.

Based on experimentation, the `CurrentCulture`, `CurrentUICulture` and `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion` are **not** used, for determining "local time".

Instead if you go to Windows, *Control Panel → Clock, Language, and Region → Date and Time → tab Date and Time → section Time zone → button Change time zone...*, changing that zone seems to work.

Of course, if Windows registry contains wrong settings for Italy, typically the ID `"W. Europe Standard Time"` (not `"Romance Standard Time"`, not `"Central European Standard Time"`), on your particular machine, that would be a problem.

Comment: In the registry path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> CURRENTCONTROLSET -> CONTROL -> TIMEZONEINFORMATION the timezoninfoKey is set corrected "W. Europe Standard Time" but i notice the key "DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled" set to "1" in the 4.5 machine and "0" in the 4.0 machine although i changed it and the problem didn't change.

Comment: I don't have the problem. With me, `DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled` is `0`, and `DaylightStart` is `00 00 03 00 05 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` (which hopefully means "last Sunday in March").

Comment: What os do you have in your machine?

Comment: @Riccardo Windows 7 SP1.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class?

```
DateTime dateUsing45 = new DateTime(2011, 4, 7); // ticks 634377312000000000
dateUsing45.ToUniversalTime(); //ticks  **634377276000000000    

TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
var isDaylightST = cstZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(dateUsing45);
```